# Performance of protobuf-net vs DataContractSerializer over WCF

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, protobuf-net

I tested protobuf serialization and it seems that for below a certain quantity of objects, it's slower than regular datacontract serialization. The transmission size is bigger using DataContractSerializer but during serialization and deserialization it is faster to use DataContractSerializer

Do you think this is normal or did I made a mistake?

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Toto
{
    [DataMember]
    public string NomToto { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string PrenomToto { get; set; }
}
```

here is my class for datacontract this is the same for protobuf

```
[ProtoContract]
public partial class Titi
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string NomTiti { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string PrenomTiti { get; set; }
}
```

here's my methods for WCF services with protobuf (same for datacontract without ms )

```
public class TitiService : ITitiService
{
    public byte[] GetAllTitis()
    {
        List<Titi> titiList = new List<Titi>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        {
            var titi = new Titi
            {
                NomTiti = "NomTiti" + i,
                PrenomTiti = "PrenomTiti" + i
            };
            titiList.Add(titi);
        }
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, titiList);

        byte[] arr = ms.ToArray();
        return arr;
    }
}
```

The service with datacontract

```
public class TotoService : ITotoService
{
    public List<Toto> GetAllTotos()
    {
        List<Toto> totoList = new List<Toto>();
        for (int i = 0; i<20000; i++)
        {
            var toto = new Toto
            {
                NomToto = "NomToto" + i,
                PrenomToto = "PrenomToto" + i
            };
            totoList.Add(toto);
        }
        return totoList;
    }
}
```

here is the client call

```
    public partial class Program
{
    static ProtobufTestAzure.Client.TitiService.TitiServiceClient TitiClient;
    static ProtobufTestAzure.Client.TotoService.TotoServiceClient TotoClient;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch stopwatch3 = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch1.Start();

        TitiClient = new ProtobufTestAzure.Client.TitiService.TitiServiceClient();
        Byte[] titiByte = TitiClient.GetAllTitis();
        TitiClient.Close();

        stopwatch1.Stop();


        stopwatch2.Start();

        var ms = new MemoryStream(titiByte);
        List<Titi> TitiList = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Titi>>(ms);

        stopwatch2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        stopwatch3.Start();

        TotoClient = new ProtobufTestAzure.Client.TotoService.TotoServiceClient();
        var TotoList = TotoClient.GetAllTotos();
        TotoClient.Close();

        stopwatch3.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Time elapse for reception (Protobuf): {0} ms ({1} éléments)", stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds, TitiList.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapse for deserialization (Protobuf : {0} ms ({1} éléments)", stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds, TitiList.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapse for réception (Datacontract Serialization) : {0} ms ({1} éléments)", stopwatch3.ElapsedMilliseconds, TotoList.Count);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and the result for 10000 objects

Time elapse for reception (Protobuf): 3359 ms (10000 elements)
Time elapse for deserialization (Protobuf): 138 ms (10000 elements)
Time elapse for reception (Datacontract Serialization): 2200ms (10000 elements)

I test it whith 20000 objects 
It gave me for the first call

Time elapse for reception (Protobuf): 11258ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for deserialization (Protobuf): 133ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for reception (Datacontract Serialization): 3726ms (20000 elements)

for the second call

Time elapse for reception (Protobuf): 2844 ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for deserialization (Protobuf): 141 ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for reception (Datacontract Serialization): 7541 ms (20000 elements)

for the third

Time elapse for reception (Protobuf): 2767ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for deserialization (Protobuf): 145 ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for reception (Datacontract Serialization): 3989 ms (20000 elements)

After MTOM activation on 'Protobuf transfert' it gaves me:

for first call

Time elapse for reception (Protobuf): 3316 ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for deserialization (Protobuf): 63 ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for reception (Datacontract Serialization): 3769 ms (20000 elements)

for second call

Time elapse for reception (Protobuf): 2279 ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for deserialization (Protobuf): 57 ms (20000 elements)
Time elapse for reception (Datacontract Serialization): 3959 ms (20000 elements)

I add this part of code for objects size

```
            long totoSize = new long();
        using (Stream s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(s, totoList);
            totoSize = s.Length;
        }

        long titiSize = titiByte.Count();
```

it gave me 637780 with protobuf and 1038236 with DataContractSerializer
Durations for call are better and more stable this morning
first call
protobuf = 2498 ms
datacontract = 5085 ms

second call
protobuf = 3649 ms
datacontract = 3840 ms

third call
protobuf = 2498 ms
datacontract = 5085 ms

Comment: How can you possibly expect someone telling you if you made a mistake without showing what you actually *made*, like for example showing the code you have tested (the two versions of it)?

Comment: Could you post your method and code, if it exists, for testing?

Comment: btw, regular XML serialization != datacontract serialization; the two are related but very different. But I echo the points above; without more context this is impossible to comment on.

Comment: sorry for the mistake with XML serialization and Datacontract Serialization, I use the last one, I edit with my code

Comment: Perhaps warmup effects interfere. i.e. the first connection is more expensive than the following ones because something needs to be initialized.

Comment: Add a call to both services at the beginning of the code.

Comment: I'm re-hosting my project on azure, the first test I made is for 10000 objects, i'll test it with 20000, I ll give you results on five minutes with more calls

Comment: right; *now* we're talking - I'll take a quick look and get back to you (I'm the author of protobuf-net, btw)

Comment: I know it Marc,I just edit the results with a call for 20000 objects and protobuf's better after the first call

Comment: @Ange - what transport are you using, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Ange - btw, you can use `Serializer.PrepareSerializer<Titi>()` somewhere during app-startup if you want to minimise any delayed costs.

Comment: @Marc I use default one  (BasicHttpBinding) I don't configure the web.config, I'll take a look on Serializer.PrepareSerializer<Titi>()

Comment: @Ange - cool, that is my preferred binding; can you enable MTOM? (see messageEncoding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx)

Comment: @Marc I edit my first post whith MTOM results but i'm not comfortable whith web.config, if you need mine tell me .

Comment: @Ange - the numbers are jumping around a bit oddly, for my liking. But: we're looking at what, 60ms to deserialize 20k items; 3micro-seconds each; that is pretty damned speedy by any measure - at that point, I'd start measuring the payload size instead - see if you can snag that in kb/MB/etc. It *looks* like maybe the network speed isn't predictable, so worry about size instead perhaps?

Comment: @Marc I edit my message with objects size for protobuf and datraContractSerializer

Comment: @Marc I test it with WireShark it gave me around 700 Ko for protobuf and 2Mo for dataContractSerializer, what a good job you made

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some factors that impact performance:

- is the serializer *prepared*? This is automatic on the first use per-type; the first time through, it needs to do quite a bit of inspection etc to figure out how your model works. You can offset this by calling `Serializer.PrepareSerializer<YourType>()` somewhere during startup

  - or as an alternative, in v2 (available as "alpha") you can pre-generate the serializer as a dll if you need the fastest possible cold-start performance
- what is the transport? in particular with WCF, you need to keep in mind how your `byte[]` is encoded (this isn't a problem on sockets, of course); for example, can the transport use MTOM? or is it base-64 encoding the `byte[]`?

  - and note also that it is possible that `Stream` and `byte[]` are handled differently; if you can measure the bandwidth, you might want to try both
  - basic-http with MTOM enabled is my preference for WCF transports if *absolute speed* is your aim; or sockets if you want to get closer to the limit